# React Material Icons Morphing

Tags: reactjs, svg, icons, material-ui

I'm creating a little radio player in ReactJS and Material UI.
Actually I'm using this code to show Play or Pause button:

```js
<IconButton className="player-control-play" onClick={this.togglePlay}>
    { (player_state.playing) ? <PauseIcon /> : <PlayArrowRoundedIcon /> }
</IconButton>
```

And for a better experience, I want to add a morphing transition when these icons are swapping. I looked at several libraries, like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-morph), but it's probably outdated cause it creates a compilation error on my app.

So I wanted to know if someone has any suggestion to achieve this! :)

Thanks